# Which type of webcam to buy for skype v. 4.1.20 on Ubuntu v. 12.10?

Tags: hardware, webcam

I got a laptop (core 2 duo, 2 GB ram) without a webcam and using Ubuntu v. 12.10 OS. As I wish to make skype video calls with my Family I wish to buy a webcam. My budget is low, so I can't spent a lot on it. As I haven't found any webcam suggestions for the Ubuntu 12.10 OS, but only for earlier OS versions, could you suggest me a webcam type(s) that I could use for skype v. 4.1.0.20?

Regards

Endre

Comment: all standard webcame does work.

Answer (score 0):

A webcam for ubuntu 12.04 shut work for ubuntu 12.10 but for ubuntu 11.10 or older sometimes dosent work.
If your internet speed is quik i recomend you a one with HQ if it isn't d'ont buy it becouse de image is going slow, some seconds after. The most webcams are cometivile with ubuntu but it dosen't said.